# Scraping a 'href' from a <span> with no class inside a<div>

Tags: python, web-scraping

i am pretty new to scraping with BeatifulSoup and python and I am having some difficulties trying to get a href inside a span but it has no class.. The following portion of code is from a phpbb forum, i have no problem scraping all the  href but for some reason i cannot figure it out how to grab what is inside the span..

```
<div class="col-md-48 post-text" data-topic="6693rw38" data-forum="2">
<br>
<br>
<a href="http://imgshare.net/img-5ba3dt3ad8a24.html" target="_blank" class="postlink" rel="nofollow"></a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="http://imgshare.net/img-5baefr1a51a49.html" target="_blank" class="postlink" rel="nofollow"></a>
<br>
<br>
<span>
    <a href="https://k2s.cc/file/5c745ce5g9193/toyota.mp4" target="_blank">https://k2s.cc/file/5c745ce5g9193/toyota.mp4</a>
</span>
<br>
<br>
<a href="http://imgshare.net/img-5ba34d1q805b8.html" target="_blank" class="postlink" rel="nofollow"></a>
<br>
<br>
<span>
    <a href="https://k2s.cc/file/b28gr283ef76e/ford.mp4" target="_blank">https://k2s.cc/file/b28gr283ef76e/ford.mp4</a>
</span>
```

This will give me all the 'href' inside the a tag:

```
url ='somephpbbforum.com'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')  

link = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'col-md-48')

for div in link:          
    all_links = [link1['href'] for link1 in div.find_all('a')]
    print(all_links)
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like this (using css selctors):

```
all_links = [s['href'] for s in soup.select('div.col-md-48 > a[href]')]
all_links
```

output:

```
['http://imgshare.net/img-5ba3dt3ad8a24.html',
 'http://imgshare.net/img-5baefr1a51a49.html',
 'http://imgshare.net/img-5ba34d1q805b8.html']
```

Edit:

To get the text content of these nodes, use

```
all_links2 = [s.text for s in soup.select('div.col-md-48 > span > a[href]')]
all_links2
```

Output:

```
['https://k2s.cc/file/5c745ce5g9193/toyota.mp4',
 'https://k2s.cc/file/b28gr283ef76e/ford.mp4']
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.. your code makes absolutely sense but for some reason it returns empty lists.. also what i am trying to scrape is what is inside the span --> a --> href..

Comment: @AtApi The output in the answer is what's inside the `<a href="xxxx"]>` node in the sample html in your question. As to why you're getting empty lists - you may need to add the actual url to your question to answer that.

Comment: i get it, but what i am trying to scrape is the href inside the span on line 10 and line 18

<a href="https://k2s.cc/file/5c745ce5g9193/toyota.mp4" for example
and
<a href="https://k2s.cc/file/b28gr283ef76e/ford.mp4"

 thank you for your help

Comment: @AtApi I see; you are looking for the text nodes, not the `link` attribute values. See edit.

Comment: Thank you buddy! i still get an empty list but i think you put me in the right track, i will inspect the html better to see why i am getting the empty list but i really appreciate your help!!!!,